# How did C.C get her scar?

Tags: code-geass

In Code Geass, when we see C.C mainly topless we see that she has [a scar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz1m3.jpg) on her left breast.

The first time we see this is when Lelouch tried to get C.C to move away from the Lancelot when she's feeding Suzaku shock images to destabilize him. when Lelouch touches her he sees her memories and there is a scene where C.C is naked in a river and there is a close shot of her scar.

However in the scenes were we see when C.C obtained the Code I can't really see the scar on her when she's in the church naked talking to the nun who gave her Geass. After C.C is covered in blood from killing the Nun who gave her Geass i still don't see the scar.

The scar itself kinda looks like a trident and not the Geass Sigil which questions if it's even linked to Geass itself. So i am wondering, when and how did C.C get this scar? also given how she been shot in the head and stabbed with shrapnel and healed completely how come the scar hasn't healed as well?

Comment: after she killed the nun, she lost her loving geass and all of townspeople seems to burned her for being a witch . . .

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, C.C. did not kill the Nun. The Nun's intent was to force C.C. to take her Code, and once C.C.'s Geass matured, attacked her to make her do so, and then killed herself. C.C. receives her scar from the Nun, during that altercation.

Presumably, the Nun tried to draw a Geass symbol, but it was done imperfectly.

Presumably, the scar persists because it was one of C.C.'s features before her death, so it doesn't go away completely.

Answer (score 1):

It was revealed in the Nightmare Of Nunnally that during the Hundred Years War C.C. was the rival of Joan of Arc. Joan was known as the Witch of Orleans, where as C.C. was the Witch of Britannia and she served under Henry VI. In a meeting between C.C. and Joan she received her scar.

Comment: are you able to answer the second part? "given how she been shot in the head and stabbed with shrapnel and healed completely how come the scar hasn't healed as well"

Comment: The Lelouch of the Rebellion, Nightmare of Nunally, and Suzaku of the Counter Attack manga have different storylines altogether. I don't believe the Nunally and Suzaku spinoff are considered canon.

Comment: Officially speaking no they are not considered canon but that is the only time they ever actually mention the scar. Also sorry but they gave not actual explanation for why the scar will not heal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to give my interpretation of what happened since it doesn't seem to be one that I've heard elsewhere.

I believe that the scar appeared after she had obtained the Code from the nun, and she was subject to torture because of the belief that she was a witch. As we know, those with the Code can still be wounded and "killed", but their injuries heal very quickly and they come back to life. It's possible that this particular injury was just fresh enough to remain visible at this time. What's more - this injury is right over her heart. Maybe it isn't supposed to be a Geass sigil at all, and is actually a deep wound caused by someone cutting her heart out (this would also explain why it is taking longer to heal). Of course, it could just as easily be a step in some sort of cultist method that the witch hunters came up with to try and kill her based on the sigil on her forehead.

Regardless, this cause and reasoning would answer the question regarding why her other injuries healed, but this one hadn't seemed to. Additionally, there is a scene during the sequence where C.C. has amnesia in which she mistakenly believes that Lelouch wants to have sex, and begins to remove her top. In this scene, her top is easily high enough that the scar should be visible, but no scar can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

The Nun attacked her and caused that wound forcing C.C. to defend herself and kill the Nun instead. Which is what the Nun wanted anyways. The damaged the Nun did, did not get healed, because it's at that moment when the Nun dies, that C.C. gets the Code from her and is now the Code user. So because the wound occurred before and not after C.C. became a Code user, it must of only healed naturally. I believe a Geass user who obtains a Code doesn't necessarily mean they activated it right then and there. C.C. must of activated the Code at a later date, probably after the wound had healed naturally. Perhaps after killing the Nun in self defense and thus obtaining the Code, C.C. fled the scene and eventually healed, only to be captured and blamed for the Nuns death and accused of being a witch and ultimately murdered by a mob in retaliation of the death of the Nun. Then upon death her Code activates and she resurrects as the immortal Geass distributor that the Nun was before her with that scar. As becoming immortal is basically freezing the person at the current state they are at when activating the Code. If LeLouch resurrects, he will probably either have a scar in his chest or a hole. One or the other, assuming his Code activated upon his death.